# Which is the easiest functional programming language for someone who has background in imperative languages?

Tags: functional-programming

I would like to learn a functional language in order to broaden my horizon. I have knowledge of Python and C/C++ and I want a language to be easy to learn from someone who comes from the imperative domain of languages. I don't care if the language is powerful enough. I just want a language in order to learn the basic of functional programming and then I will try for a more difficult (and powerful language).

Thanks

Comment: Haskell is often recommended to learn functional paradigm as it is pure. It is not easy, but maybe you could get confused by mixing procedural and functional paradigm in other languages (Scala and others).

Comment: Elm.  https://elm-lang.org/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend [pure-lang](https://agraef.github.io/pure-lang/) for these pedagogical ends. It's also plenty powerful. If you want something more popular / with more community support, then I'd recommend Scheme or OCaml, depending on whether you'd rather deal with unfamiliar syntax (go with Scheme) or deal with unfamiliar typing (go with OCaml) first. SML and F# are only slightly different from OCaml. Others have or will mention Clojure, Scala, and Haskell.

Clojure is a variant of Scheme, with its own idiosyncracies (e.g. no tail-call optimization), so using it would be a way of starting with Scheme. I'd expect you'd have an easier time with a less idiosyncratic Scheme implementation though. [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org/index.html) is what's often used for teaching. Scala looks to be fundamentally similar to OCaml, but this is based on only casual familiarity.

Unlike Haskell, the other languages mentioned all have two advantages: (1) evaluation-order is eager by default, though you can get lazy evaluation by specifically requesting it. In Haskell's the reverse. (2) Mutation is available, though much of the libraries and code you'll see doesn't use it. I actually think it's pedagogically better to learn functional programming while at the same time having an eye on how it interacts with side-effects, and working your way to monadic-style composition somewhat down the road. So I think this is an advantage. Some will tell you that it's better to be thrown into Haskell's more-quarantined handling of mutaton first, though.

Robert Harper at CMU [has some nice blog posts on teaching functional programming](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/category/teaching-2/). As I understand, he also prefers languages like OCaml for teaching.

Among the three classes of languages I recommended (Pure, Scheme and friends, OCaml and friends), the first two have dynamic typing. The first and third have explicit reference cells (as though in Python, you restricted yourself to never reassiging a variable but you could still change what's stored at a list index). Scheme has implicit reference cells: variables themselves look mutable, as in C and Python, and the reference cell handling is done under the covers. In languages like that, you often have some form of explicit reference cell available too (as in the example I just gave in Python, or using mutable pairs/lists in Racket...in other Schemes, including the Scheme standard, those are the default pairs/lists).

One virtue Haskell does have is some textbooks are appearing for it. (I mean this sincerely, not snarkily.) What books/resources to use is another controversial issue with many wars/closed questions. SICP as others have recommended has many fans and also some critics. There seem to me to be many good choices. I won't venture further into those debates.

Answer (score 4):

At first, read Structure and Implementation of Computer Programs. I recommend Lisp (for, example, it's dialect Scheme) as first functional programming language.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion. I have myself benefited a lot from SICP and doing the exercises. I will also strongly recommend to study SICP.

Comment: Possibly the book name is _Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs_

Answer (score 3):

Another option is Clojure, which I'm given to understand is more "purely" functional than Scheme/Racket (don't ask me about the details here) and possibly similar enough to let you use it in conjunction with SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, a highly recommended book also suggested by another answer).

Comment: Clojure emphasizes the use of immutable data structures in combination with pure functions... so those are strong pillars of support for this argument.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to learn a functional language in order to broaden my horizon. I have knowledge of Python and C/C++ and I want a language to be easy to learn from someone who comes from the imperative domain of languages. I don't care if the language is powerful enough. I just want a language in order to learn the basic of functional programming and then I will try for a more difficult (and powerful language).

Great question!

I had done BASIC, Pascal, assembler, C and C++ before I started doing functional programming in the late 1990s. Then I started using two functional languages at about the same time, Mathematica and OCaml, and was using them exclusively within a few years. In particular, OCaml let me write imperative code which looked like the code I had been writing before. I found that valuable as a learner because it let me compare the different approaches which made the advantages of ML obvious.

However, as others have mentioned, the core benefit of Mathematica and OCaml is pattern matching and that is not technically related to functional programming. I have subsequently looked at many other functional languages but I have no desire to go back to a language that lacks pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably off-topic because it is going to result in endless language wars, but here's a general bit of advice:

There are a class of functional programming languages which are sometimes called "mostly functional", in that they permit some imperative features where you want them.  Examples include Standard ML, OCaml, F#, and Scala.  You might consider one of these if you want to be able to get a grip on the functional idiomatic style while still being able to achieve things in reasonably familiar ways.

I've used Standard ML extensively in the past, but if you're looking for something that has a bit less of a learning curve, I'd personally recommend Scala, which is my second-favourite programming language.  The reasons for this include the prevalence of libraries, a healthy-sized community, and the availability of nice books and tutorials to help you getting started (particularly if you have ever had any dealings with Java).

Comment: I am wondering if the ability to fallback to imperative style when you want may become an impediment to learning the functional style.

Comment: The question did specifically ask for "easiest to learn", so while I agree that having an imperative fallback might not be the best long-term strategy, it does reduce the learning curve such that you don't have to learn how IO works in a pure setting at the same time as everything else :)

Comment: Yeah, I do expect this question to be closed soon.

Answer (score 1):

One element that was not discussed is the availability of special pattern-matching syntax for algebraic datatypes, as in Haskell, all flavors of ML, and probably several of the other languages mentioned. Pattern-matching syntax tends to help the programmer see their functions as *mathematical* functions. Haskell's syntax is sufficiently complex, and its implementations have sufficiently poor parse error messages, that syntax is a decent reason not to choose Haskell. Scheme is probably easier to learn than most other options (and Scheme probably has the king of all macro systems), but the lack of pattern matching syntax would steer me away from it for an intro to functional programming.

Comment: I completely agree about the importance of pattern matching in learning functional programming. I think it's going to be available with more or less work on most or all the choices though. Many Scheme implementations have pattern matching at least as an extension; Racket has it natively. An implementation-agnostic version is distributed with the textbook Essentials of Programming Languages. By all means someone learning FP with Scheme should make sure to exploit these facilities.

Comment: My recollection is that the syntax for pattern matching in Racket is a lot less readable and writable than the syntax to do it in ML. Am I confused? The fact that Racket doesn't have algebraic datatypes (although the PLAI sub-language does a very good job of faking them) makes matters worse.

Comment: @dfeuer I discussed that at length with the Lisp community when I was choosing between Lisp and OCaml. The Lispers would reply that Lisps might not have algebraic datatypes but they have macros which lets you write your own pattern matching library that is even more powerful because you can do full unification. However, pattern matching is ubiquitous in OCaml, F#, Haskell and Scala whereas unification is almost unheard of in Lisp, Scheme, Racket and Clojure. So I think it is fair to say the Lispers lost that one. Pattern matching is hugely valuable which makes MLs a lot better than Lisps.

Comment: @AndrewC, I don't know any of the history, but it appears that cvs.haskell.org no longer exists. I would bet that since everything else Haskell has switched to either git or darcs, no one wanted to maintain the CVS infrastructure anymore to support an obsolete implementation.